# remove 4 letters from a string, before the extension

Tags: javascript

How can you remove letters from a string in jquery

So for example if you had the following

```
var gif = "example_one.gif";
```

how could i out put it so it would show

```
"example.gif"
```

So remove the last four characters but keep the extension?

Comment: This isn't a jQuery problem, it's a JavaScript problem. jQuery doesn't give you any special tools for string manipulation.

Comment: Use substring function

Comment: What is the format of the input strings? Will they all be `example_num.ext`?

Comment: are the lengths fixed? Will it always be `_one` and `.xyz`?

Comment: For questions like this, you should include attempted solutions, as well as explicit detail around how to handle edge-cases. Experiment with the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method and the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and see if you can make any progress, then come back for help if necessary.

Comment: Technically you're removing letters from the middle, not the end of your string.

Comment: Will it always be the four characters before the period (assuming only one period is allowed)? Or are there cases like `_five`? Should it be everything following the underscore, but before the period (in which case regex is a good solution)? Details...

Comment: Would have been GREAT to know the start of what's removed is `_` rather than the arbitrary `4` characters removed :) Either way, glad it's solved for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regex approach**
- Removes anything and including the underscore up until the extension

```
var gif = "example_one.gif";
gif = gif.replace(/(?=_).*(?=\.)/g,'');
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx7cL/)

Explanation [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/rB7oR2)

```
(?=_)        Positive Lookahead - Assert that "underscore" can be matched
.*           Matches any character (except newline)
(?=\.)       Positive Lookahead - Assert that "period" can be matched
g            modifier: Global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: +1 This seems like the only solution which is flexible enough to extend beyond the simple cases, assuming that after `"_one"` will be `"_two"`, etc. Might be good to explain the regex a bit as well.

Comment: Very well. Added regex explanation.

Answer (score 2):

that what you want?

```
var gif =  "example_one.gif" ;
gif = gif.substr(0, gif.indexOf("_")) + gif.substr(gif.indexOf("."), gif.length);
```

Comment: Strings don't have a "lenght" property :)

Comment: if I were you give it a read here  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp. then we talked

Comment: I ran the code and it worked, just took the point that should not thereby:"examplegif"

Comment: Well, it works now that `length` is spelled right. But I do like that this solution generalizes beyond the case of `"_one"` as well, even if a bit wordy, so +1 all the same :)

Comment: Forgive me, the code was the same error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

### Walking through it the most basic way...

First find the `.`:

```
var gif = "example_one.gif";
var end = gif.lastIndexOf(".")
```

Then split the string:

```
var name_only = gif.substring(0,end)
```

Then take out what you want taken out:

```
var trimmed = name_only.substring(0,name_only.length-5)
```

Then put your extension back:

```
var cleaned = trimmed + gif.substring(end-1,gif.length)
```

Check it:

```
alert( cleaned )
```

---

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/G27HN/

---

#### Or do it with a reusable function! http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/wNu8U/

*WITH* ability to change length of trim job needed:

```
function cleanEnding( named, count ) {
    if ( count == undefined ) count = 4
    var end = named.lastIndexOf( "." )
    var name_only = named.substring( 0, end )
    var trimmed = name_only.substring( 0, name_only.length - count-1 )
    var cleaned = trimmed + named.substring( end-1, named.length )
    return cleaned
}

//de You CAN pass in a number after this.
//de The function defaults to trimming out 4 before the extension.
alert( cleanEnding( "example_one.gif" ) )
```

Comment: ( I fixed that in the fiddle and answer ) /facepalm/

Comment: Nice, good answer, assuming the length of the part to be removed doesn't change. OP hasn't given a specific requirement anyway.

Comment: [ Haha. That's what I was just adding. Updated while you were commenting :) ]

Answer (score 0):

If its always the last four characters before the extension (and the extension is three characters):

```
var gif = "example_one.gif";
var gif2 = gif.substring(0, gif.length - 8) + gif.substring(gif.length - 4);
console.log(gif2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2cYrj/

Answer (score 0):

```
var gif = "example_one.gif";
var str = gif.split('.');
str[0] = str[0].slice(0, -4);
gif = str.join('.');
console.log(gif);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = gif.split('.');
var newstring = parts[0].substr(0, parts[0].length-4) + "." + parts[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
gif.replace('_one', '')
```

Does this help you or you want it more general?